# Using VBA to calculate latest dates of certain tasks?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a spreadsheet to log the tasks completed and in progress of a project. I was to generate some VBA code that can identify the latest delivery date within a task. However, in each task there are various sub tasks.

So the boundaries are the task which are whole numbers, and in between these whole numbers e.g. 46 and 46, are sub tasks.

The latest date needs to be calculated by examining the dates of the tasks between each whole number. E.g. 46.1,46.2,46.3 etc.

Would i be better by using the excel functions or would it be easier to use code?

e.g. the example of an excel function but in vba i would use.

````
 Worksheets("Activity Overview").cells(n, "E").value = "=IFERROR(IF(AGGREGATE(14,7,'Sub Tasks'!S:S/(('Sub Tasks'!A:A>='Activity Overview'!A" & n & ")*('Sub Tasks'!A:A<'Activity Overview'!A" & n + 1 & ")),1),AGGREGATE(14,7,'Sub Tasks'!S:S/(('Sub Tasks'!A:A>='Activity Overview'!A" & n & ")*('Sub Tasks'!A:A<'Activity Overview'!" & n + 1 & ")),1),""""),"""")"
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MAXIFS():

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&E1,A:A,"<"&E1+1)
```

[image]

---

If one does not have MAXIFS then use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,$B$1:$B$6/(($A$1:$A$6>=E1)*($A$1:$A$6<E1+1)),1)
```

AGGREGATE is an array type formula and as such the references should be limited to the data range.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `SUMPRODUCT`. It basically filters all values between the base value (>=49) and less than the base value plus one (<50).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` available in Excel 2010+

- Get Data from Table/Range
- Change the `Date` column to `Date` format (it defaults to `DateTime`)
- Create a custom column which is the Integer of the Task column and Name it `Main Task`

  - `=Int64.From([Task])`
- Delete the original Task column
- `Group By` the `Main Task` column

  - New Column Name `Latest Date`
  - Operation:  `Max`
  - Column: `Target Delivery Date`

[image]

- If there are any nulls in the `Latest Date` Column (from tasks with no delivery dates), you can either leave them, or filter them out.

#### Data

[image]

#### Results

[image]

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Task", type number}, {"Target Delivery Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Main Task", each Int64.From([Task])),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Main Task"}, {{"Latest Date", each List.Max([Target Delivery Date]), type date}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([Latest Date] <> null))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```